# Invalid wire-type error in protobuf.net on a new MemoryStream

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to parse a protobuf message received from an external service. I know that this data is a valid protobuf message, and I know I'm not accidentally mangling it before I send it to the deserializer. Here's my code:

```
public static T DeserializeFromBytes<T>(byte[] encoded)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(encoded);
    stream.SetLength(encoded.Length);
    stream.Capacity = encoded.Length;
    T decoded = (T)Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
    stream.Close();
    return decoded;
}
```

and I'm calling this method like this:

```
MercuryReply header = ProtobufUtils.DeserializeFromBytes<MercuryReply>(Convert.FromBase64String(metadata[0]));
```

`metadata[0]` is a base64 string that includes a protobuf message. A sample looks something like this:

> CjRobTovL21ldGFkYXRhL2FsYnVtL2M1MzU3MTA0M2U4ODQ3YjRhODc1YzVlNmZiNmNiZTdmEhp2bmQuc3BvdGlmeS9tZXRhZGF0YS1hbGJ1bSCQAzIYCgpNRC1WZXJzaW9uEgoxMzcwMzc5NTA1Mg8KBk1DLVRUTBIFNjk2MDQyGQoPTUMtQ2FjaGUtUG9saWN5EgZwdWJsaWMyDwoHTUMtRVRhZxIELD8q+Q==

Now, when I run the program, I get an Invalid wire-type error when deserializing. I can't see any reason why this would be happening. Is there something obvious here that I missed?

Comment: what is `T` here? (what does `MercuryReply` look like?), and where did that base-64 come from? (i.e. do we know that the base-64 represents a valid message?)

Comment: I see you've marked as accepted - I don't suppose you can provide any more info on what the actual problem was, for the benefit of later readers?

Comment: Oh. Somehow I didn't notice these comments, sorry. It turns out that the reason it was throwing that error was due to the message containing a string but `MercuryReply` had it as an int. I'm not sure how it worked originally (I'm half-porting some code from python), but it probably has something to do with the dynamic typing of Python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That (string vs int) makes perfect sense for a wire-type mismatch error - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That usually means either:

- the binary is not valid ([people make a mess of binary *all* the time](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html); your use of base-64 is perfectly fine, though, if it needs to be stored/transferred as a string)
- there is a mismatch in the data (for example, field `2` is `varint` in the data, but is a `string` in the type)

Based on you binary, I've pieced together that `MercuryReply` might look something like:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class MercuryReply
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get { return headers; } }
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> headers
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

(the names here are pure guesswork based on what the data looks like; protobuf does not transmit names - only the numeric keys, i.e. `1`/`2`/`4`/`6` in this example)

which works *fine* when tested with:

```
static void Main()
{
    var encoded = Convert.FromBase64String("CjRobTovL21ldGFkYXRhL2FsYnVtL2M1MzU3MTA0M2U4ODQ3YjRhODc1YzVlNmZiNmNiZTdmEhp2bmQuc3BvdGlmeS9tZXRhZGF0YS1hbGJ1bSCQAzIYCgpNRC1WZXJzaW9uEgoxMzcwMzc5NTA1Mg8KBk1DLVRUTBIFNjk2MDQyGQoPTUMtQ2FjaGUtUG9saWN5EgZwdWJsaWMyDwoHTUMtRVRhZxIELD8q+Q==");

    MercuryReply header = ProtobufUtils.DeserializeFromBytes<MercuryReply>(encoded);

}
```

(using your `DeserializeFromBytes` method)

So: if that isn't working for you, the important two questions are:

- is that the *actual* base-64 from your real code at runtime? or is that just what you think it *should be in theory*?
- what does your `MercuryReply` class look like?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as Marc Gravell points out in the comments, I'm on the wrong track. Please disregard my answer but I'm leaving it since the comment discussion is valuable.

protobuf-net is not the same thing as protobuf, and does not adhere to the algorithm in a uniform, cross-platform compatible way. protobuf-net is a .NET contract based serializer that happens to use protobuf, but does not implement protobuf "to spec" for the purposes of interoperability. For example: protobuf-net is aware of the .NET types, whereas Google's protobuf is not aware of .NET types. See this links for more:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: I disagree with your description; protobuf-net does **very much** adhere to the algorithm and specification; it has some support for types not mentioned in the specification, which it handles in ways that are fully compatible with the specification. If you can show any way in which it doesn't work "to spec" with anything defined in the specification, or any way in which the *additional* types are implemented in a way that is not 100% compliant with the wire specification, I would be very interested to see it.

Comment: Hi Marc - thanks for commenting! No argument that it almost entirely matches the algorithm and specification, but there are some differences that I've noticed. One difference that I've encountered is in the decode, specifically in empty set decoding. The Protobuf specification calls for an empty set to be instantiated when the *repeated* term/field fails to match. In my experience with protobuf-net, encoding an empty collection such as a List or IEnumerable works properly (does not encode), but decoding an empty collection yields null instead of empty set.

Comment: that isn't really a feature of the decode, and I'm pretty sure that behavior is not formally defined as part of the protobuf specification itself - however, in the case of protobuf-net that would (and is) better addressed by defaulting the list / etc to a non-null value in the constructor. If you start from .proto (as you would when doing cross-platform), protogen will do this automatically, so you won't ever get null collections

Comment: Awesome, then I am simply mistaken. Thanks for the input Marc!

Comment: to be explicit: any such difference should never cause an "invalid wire type" error (this question)

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, using postman:
The proto was updated in the backend code, but the postman still uses the old proto file and that was causing the error.

using the latest proto file from the postman solved the issue for me.